# while python multithreading, one indenting at IF changes everything

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I am following the tutorialspoint and in their case they write it as I copy paste it, but as I tried to reproduce it in my pycharm, it gave the error that indeed, the IF is unnecessarily indented. So, I dedented, but when I do, then I dont get a synchronized threading Only thread 3 does something, threads 1 and 2 just get started but never perform any job, then all leave. However, apparently, it works fine for the tutorial authors and they dont indent the IF . I am using python 3, so I had to lower case the queue import.

```
import Queue
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.q = q
   def run(self):
      print "Starting " + self.name
      process_data(self.name, self.q)
      print "Exiting " + self.name

def process_data(threadName, q):
   while not exitFlag:
      queueLock.acquire()
         if not workQueue.empty(): #THIS IS THE ONE THEY INDENT
            data = q.get()
            queueLock.release()
            print "%s processing %s" % (threadName, data)
         else:
            queueLock.release()
         time.sleep(1)

threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in threadList:
   thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
   thread.start()
   threads.append(thread)
   threadID += 1

# Fill the queue
queueLock.acquire()
for word in nameList:
   workQueue.put(word)
queueLock.release()

# Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
   pass

# Notify threads it's time to exit
exitFlag = 1

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
   t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the conclusion is that the example at Tutorialspoint has that error when it comes to the IF indentation. There should not be such thing. This means that the results they show definitively don't correspond to the code.

So:

I have made two changes: 
First, I dedented the IF and the ones else and the sleep.
Second, I could not see how I could be calling the workqueue if I had not created it yet. So I moved the snippet of queue creation above the call.

This is how it should be in Python 3:

```
 import queue
    import threading
    import time

    exitFlag = 0

    class myThread (threading.Thread):
       def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)
          self.threadID = threadID
          self.name = name
          self.q = q
       def run(self):
          print ("Starting" + self.name)
          process_data(self.name, self.q)
          print ("Exiting" + self.name)

    def process_data(threadName, q):
       while not exitFlag:
          queueLock.acquire()
          if not workQueue.empty():
                data = q.get()
                queueLock.release()
                print ("%s processing %s" % (threadName, data))
          else:
                queueLock.release()
          time.sleep(1)

    threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
    nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
    queueLock = threading.Lock()
    workQueue = queue.Queue(10)
    threads = []
    threadID = 1


    # Fill the queue
    queueLock.acquire()
    for word in nameList:
       workQueue.put(word)
    queueLock.release()


    # Create new threads
    for tName in threadList:
       thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
       thread.start()
       threads.append(thread)
       threadID += 1


    # Wait for queue to empty
    while not workQueue.empty():
       pass

    # Notify threads it's time to exit
    exitFlag = 1

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for t in threads:
       t.join()
    print ("Exiting Main Thread")
```

And the results I get, (which looks good), are:

```
StartingThread-1
Thread-1 processing One                                                                                                                                                         
StartingThread-2                                                                                                                                                                
Thread-2 processing Two                                                                                                                                                         
StartingThread-3                                                                                                                                                                
Thread-3 processing Three                                                                                                                                                       
Thread-1 processing Four                                                                                                                                                        
Thread-2 processing Five                                                                                                                                                        
ExitingThread-3                                                                                                                                                                 
ExitingThread-1                                                                                                                                                                 
ExitingThread-2                                                                                                                                                                 
Exiting Main Thread
```

Comment: Take a look at the Python docs for [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#queue.Queue.join).  Queues are already synchronized and don't need an additional lock.  `.task_done()` should be called for each `.get()` and `workqueue.join()` can then be used to determine if all the items are complete.

Comment: Thank you. I dont know if the "answer" that I have posted is visible for everybody as it takes 2 days before I can approve it, but, with a minor change, namely moving the workqueue above the snippet that calls it, it now prints out in an order that makes sense.

Comment: I find the python official documentation anything but pedagogic. It is a reference guide for experts. I usually never understand it. For the queue and task done that you mention, I use this easy tutorial: https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/

Comment: You become an expert by reading the official documentation.  I find many outside tutorials *almost* correct.  Official documentation gets corrected by the experts.

Answer (score 1):

You found an answer, but just for illustration, here's a simplified version that doesn't require global exit flags and removes the unnecessary lock:

```
import queue
import threading
import time

def process_data():
    name = threading.current_thread().name
    print('Starting',name)
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if data is None: # Check for exit special value
            break
        print(name,'processing',data)
        time.sleep(1)
        q.task_done()
    print('Exiting',name)

thread_count = 3
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
q = queue.Queue()

# Create new threads
threads = [threading.Thread(target=process_data) for _ in range(thread_count)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

# Fill the queue
for word in nameList:
    q.put(word)

# Wait for queue to empty
q.join()

# Notify threads it's time to exit
for t in threads:
    q.put(None) # Special value put in queue indicating to exit

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print('Exiting main thread')
```

Output:

```
Starting Thread-1
Starting Thread-2
Starting Thread-3
Thread-1 processing One
Thread-3 processing Three
Thread-2 processing Two
Thread-3 processing Four
Thread-2 processing Five
Exiting Thread-1
Exiting Thread-3
Exiting Thread-2
Exiting main thread
```

Comment: In your results, could it be added which thread is performing which task at which time? in my output I indicate that, but I dont know if in the order of your lines that would print out so.

Comment: @MartinDuiceivic Sure just update the processing print with the thread name.  See my update.  Also remember the order is arbitrary.  The threads are run in parallel so only the order of messages from the same thread are predictable.